# elementary OS update?

Tags: release-loki, updates

I'm new to Linux...I already have the Elementary OS installed on my computer. In order to get the update, what's the simplest way of getting Loki? Are there any terminal commands I can run?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install the 0.4.0 loki iso. There is no dist-upgrade option available from older versions.